# Google cloud api in ruby fails execution expired while uploading a single file

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage

i׳m trying to use the api in order to upload a 500 MB file.
but i get an error after 15 min:

> sh
> Got error: Google::Cloud::Error with message: execution expired while uploading a single file: myfile.csv

When i upload 100mb+- file it works. but more then that it just fail after exactly 15 mins.

where is the problem? in my api? in google cloud settings of my bucket ?

### Environment details

- OS:mac os catlina
- Ruby version: ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin19]
- Gem name and version: cnvrg-1.10.8

### Steps to reproduce

1. cnvrg data put mydata "myfile"

### Code example

```rb
 @storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new(project_id: @project_id, credentials: @credentials, retries: 20, timeout: 999)
```

also tried:

```rb
 @storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new(project_id: @project_id, credentials: @credentials, retries: 20)
```

### Full backtrace

> sh
> Got error: Google::Cloud::Error with message: execution expired while uploading a single file: myfile.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of the Google Cloud Storage client you have specified a timeout of 999 seconds `timeout: 999`. According to [the documentation](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/Google/Cloud/Storage.html#new-class_method):

> timeout (Integer) (defaults to: nil) — Default timeout to use in requests. Optional.

So this is the cause of your error. Your request is failing after 15 minutes as it hasn't complete yet. To solves this you can set a higher timeout or remove this parameter which will set it to its default value (nil).

Comment: i already tried with nil. and its still the same, after 15 min i get the same error.

Comment: do you think about something else ?

Comment: What about setting a higher timeout?

Comment: i already did that. and it didn't work. there is anything else that choose the timeout ?do you familer with that error ?

Comment: I believe the error is produced in your network side. I could successfully upload +500MB files to a GCS bucket following the ruby sample code stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample)

Comment: i have tried from 5 computers in diffrent locations and all the same.
what can make this timeout ?

Comment: You might want to add more information such as the whole code you are using to upload the file and the file. So maybe other people can reproduce your issue and find out what is causing it.

Comment: do you know what is the limit of the timeout ?

Comment: According to the documentation there is no limit to the timeout.